# How would I print everything in a string up until the first number in python?

Tags: python, slice

I have an input file containing lines like the following:

**"Kansas City Chiefs            42"**

Each line contains a random number of spaces between the words and the numbers. I am trying to identify a way that I can slice the two values (word portion and number portion). My ideal output would be:

**"Kansas City Chiefs"**

**"42"**

Any ideas?

Comment: you could split the input on space, and then get the last item in the list. `result = input_string.split(" ")` then `result[-1]`. the `.split(" ")` would split the string at every space, and then the `[-1]` gets the last item in the list.

Comment: use regular expression

Comment: @Adam, what if the last word was chars and not numbers? Its best to use regex. ex: `Kansas City Chiefs 42 Team`

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this regex:

```
import re

your_string = "Kansas City Chiefs 42"
items = re.split(r'\s+(?=\d)|(?<=\d)\s+', your_string)

print(items)
```

you got:

```
['Kansas City Chiefs', '42']
```

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to read split as soon as you get the first number then below should work.

```py
st = "Kansas City Chiefs 42"
text_part = ""

for each in st:
    if each.isnumeric():
        break
    text_part += each
number_part = st.replace(text_part, "")
print(text_part)
print(number_part)
```

you can you .strip() on either of the values depending on whether you want to keep the spaces at the end or not

Answer (score 0):

Here's my implementation:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize

sentence = "Kansas City Chiefs 42"
tokens = word_tokenize(sentence)
word_phrases = " ".join([token for token in tokens if not token.isnumeric()])
numeric_phrase = " ".join([token for token in tokens if token.isnumeric()])
print(word_phrases)
print(numeric_phrase)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use regex in python.

```
import re
def getNumber(str):
  arr = re.findall(r'[0-9]+', str)
str1 = "Kansas City Chiefs 42"
numbers = getNumber(str1)
str_val = str1[str1.find(numbers[0]):] # Kansas City Chiefs 
print(" ".join(numbers))
# output -> 42
```

Comment: This gives all the strings with the numbers but not the string. OP is looking for the string just before the numbers.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is best to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. A code example can be very useful. Link-only responses may become invalid if the linked page changes.